# What is the meaning of ownership of a process on a window?

Tags: x11, process

In manpage of xdotool

> ```
> getwindowpid [window]
> ```
>
> Output the PID **owning** a given window. This requires effort from the
>   application owning a window and may not work for all windows. This
>   uses _NET_WM_PID property of the window. See "EXTENDED WINDOW MANAGER
>   HINTS" below for more information.

When a process is said to own a window, what does that mean? I have several guesses about it:

- Is the process the one which has created the window?
- A window is not a process, so ownership can't imply the parent-child relation between processes.
- what is the relation between a window of a process and the controlling terminal of the same process ('s session)? Is a window of a process related to terminal related signals (SIGINT, SIGHUP, SIGQUIT)?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything; any X11 client can set the `_NET_WM_PID` property on **any** window to whatever it likes, eg. `xprop -id $WINDOWID -f _NET_WM_PID 32c -set _NET_WM_PID 1` will not make your terminal window owned by `init`. Processes and/or X11 clients **do not own** windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [mosvy's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486178/what-is-the-meaning-of-ownership-of-a-process-on-a-window#comment891607_486178):

> any X11 client can set the _NET_WM_PID property on any window to whatever it likes, eg. xprop -id $WINDOWID -f _NET_WM_PID 32c -set _NET_WM_PID 1 will not make your terminal window owned by init. Processes and/or X11 clients do not own windows